# Chrome Mode - finding apps

Tags: google-chrome

Windows 8 question: If I operate Chrome in windows 8 mode instead of desktop mode, how do I get to my other programs that are open like my e-mailer and g-talk?

Answer (score 0):

All apps that are part of the Google ecosystem, as well as websites in the Chrome browser will run inside the Windows 8 Mode view.

If by "e-mailer", you mean Gmail, then what I said before applies. For anything that is not a Google app/service (including other email clients like Outlook), you'll have to Alt+Tab out of Chrome's Windows 8 Mode entirely.

Remember: Windows 8 Mode for Chrome is essentially like using Chrome OS in its own self-contained environment. You need to leave this environment to use anything else within Windows.